# Fill in missing values in DataFrame Column which is incrementing by 10

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say , Some Values in the 'Counts' column are missing. These numbers are meant to be increased by 10 with each row so '35' and '55' need to be put in place. I would want to fill in these missing values.

```
         Counts
0        25    
1        NaN
2        45
3        NaN
4        65
```

So my output should be :

```
         Counts
0        25    
1        35
2        45
3        55
4        65
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

We have `interpolate`

```
df=df.interpolate()
   Counts
0    25.0
1    35.0
2    45.0
3    55.0
4    65.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you now the pattern, you can simply recreate it:

```
start = df.iloc[0]['Counts'] # first row
end = df.iloc[-1]['Counts'] # last row
df['Counts'] = np.where(df['Counts'].notnull(), df['Counts'], 
                        np.arange(start, end + 1, 10))
```